# What is the proper use of high-res sprites on iOS with CSS?

Tags: ios, css, sprite, scale, css-sprites

I am having some serious trouble trying to get my sprites to show up right on a iPhone4+ using a high res (2x) version of my navigation sprite. Here's the code I'm using right now.

```
.pixelj a, .games a, .team a, .forums a {
    width: 156px;
    height: 35px;
    background-image: url('/assets/blogtext2x.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
/*  background-size: 156px 17px;*/  
    text-indent: -9999px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    }
```

As you can see this is for a navigation where I have all the navigation word elements in a single sprited image. I tried using "background-size" but that just squished the whole sprite into the width/height provided. If I get rid of it it shows the 2x images but doesn't make them 50% so they view correctly.

What am I doing wrong here? Here's the @media query I am using to target high-res devices:

```
@media (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
  (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
  (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
  (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
  (min-resolution: 1.5dppx),
  (max-device-width: 640px) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're absolutely on the right track here.

Essentially the process here with providing 'retina' graphics in a sprite via CSS is:

- Set up your normal sprite, with the relevant positioning/etc within your CSS to feed to non-retina devices,
- Set the background-size of this image,
- Use a media query to feed the @2x variant of the image to those devices that support it.

There are a few key things to bear in mind:

- setting `background-size` requires several declarations with different vendor prefixes to get the best browser coverage - see my code below to see what I mean
- `background-size` is the size of the non-retina variant of the background *image*, not the size of the element it sits within.  So, if the normal-size sprite image is 200px by 400px (and the high-resolution version is 400px by 800px), then it's `200px 400px` that you declare.
- `background-size` values are declared as `<width> <height>`.
- You have to declare `background-size` in the first declaration, not in the retina media-query overwrite.
- Although using `@2x` is becoming common-practice, it's not essential in web development: you could use a totally different image name.

It's very difficult to help you with your specific question without all the code, or a live URL to look at, but here's a high-level example.

In this example, I have a background-image which is 100px wide and 50px high which is positioned in the middle of the element

```
/* the element */
.element{
    background: url(../img/site/background-image.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;

    /* vendor-specfic declarations for background-size */
    -webkit-background-size: 100px 50px;
    -moz-background-size:  100px 50px;
    -o-background-size:  100px 50px;
    background-size:  100px 50px;
}

/* for retina users */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
screen and (max--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){ 
    .element{
        /* we only over-write background-image here */
       background-image: url(../img/site/background-image@2x.png);
    }
}
```

This will mean that those devices which fall into the second media query will load the `@2x` version of the background image, and will scale it to the `background-size` dimensions as declared.

Because the image is scaled back to the dimensions you set, if you're using sprites you only have to declare all the element's `background-position`s once as you usually would, and not twice to account for the larger retina graphic dimensions.

**EDIT:**
Having now seen your site, I can see exactly the problem you're having with your navigation:

[image: Screenshot]

The reason it looks like this is your CSS here (line 972 of `style2.css`):

```
.pixeljam a, .games a, .team a, .forums a {
    background: no-repeat url('/assets/blogtext2x.png');
}
```

If you change that to `background-image` and remove the `no-repeat`, then it will work (otherwise `background` resets your previous background positions).

```
.pixeljam a, .games a, .team a, .forums a {
    background-image: url('/assets/blogtext2x.png');
}
```

Comment: I figured it out, I was having trouble because I was setting the background size as the size of the area visible, not the size of the entire 1x image. It looks great now. This is visible on my dev-site, here's a [link]http://www.mindevo.com/pj/

Comment: Hi @ChaBuku - glad to hear you were able to resolve it, I expected that might have been why you were having issues (it's a fairly common misunderstanding - the spec is a little confusing at that point).  If that's your question answered, please do remember to mark the correct answer in your question (there's a green check you can click on beside each answer).  This ensures that people coming to the site with similar issues in the future will be able to find their answer as easily as possible.  by the way - love the font you're using for the titles on your site!

Comment: I've just noticed something about your site that's worth mentioning (to help with your navigation elements) - I'll edit my answer for you.

Comment: Great, yeah I was wondering why I had to reset my positioning in the media query as well, and that fixed it. What did you take that screenshot on? I've been checking it using an iPhone 4, and everything seems to look good now. I am about to start targeting landscape versions now that portrait is working out.

Comment: I have a retina MacBook, so that's where the screenshot came from.  Do take a look at that line of CSS I identified in my edit.  The reason it's happening is you're using `background` to declare your @2x background image, which positions it back to 0 0.  If you use ` instead, and remove the `no-repeat`, it will all fall back into place.